# Python - Reading HTTP Request Body

Tags: javascript, python, http

I am trying to send data to my Python server using HTTP.

My JavaScript code:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(String.fromCharCode(0xf5));
```

My Python code:

```
#sock is a socket object
header = readline(sock)
contl = 0
while(len(header) > 0):
    header = readline(sock)
    dat = header.split(': ')
    if(len(dat) >= 2):
        if(dat[0] == 'Content-Length'):
            contl = int(float(dat[1]))
print sock.recv(contl)
```

readline function:

```
def readLine(sock):
    s = ""
    while(True):
        a = sock.recv(1)
        if(len(a) < 1):
            return s
        elif(a == '\n'):
            return s
        elif(a == '\r'):
            b = sock.recv(1)
            if(b == '\n'):
                return s
            else:
                s += a + b
        else:
            s += a
```

Instead of my Python code printing `\xf5` it prints `\xc3\xb5`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is your readline function doing. Can you post the method code?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Okay, posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\xc3\xb5` is UTF-8 representation of U+00F5

```
>>> u'\xf5'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xb5'
```

You can covert it back using [`str.decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) ([`bytes.decode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) in Python 3.x):

```
>>> b'\xc3\xb5'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xf5'
```